# Using document.getElementsByName() isn't working?

Tags: javascript

The code for the second alert command works as intended (displaying the value of the element "to", but the first alert command does not work (it's supposed to do the same thing). Why is this?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getValue()
  {
  alert(document.getElementsByName("to").value);
  alert(document.forms[0].to.value);  
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input name="to" type="hidden" value="hoolah" />
<input type="button" onclick="getValue()" value="Get Value!" />
<form/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns an `HTMLCollection`. You can access the value of the first item like this:

```
document.getElementsByName("to").item(0).value
```

Or like this:

```
document.getElementsByName("to")[0].value
```

More info:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCollection

Answer (score 3):

`getElementsByName` returns all elements with the given name.  This means there can be more than one.

If you want to get the value of the first element:

```
document.getElementsByName("to")[0].value
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because it puts the element(s) into an array, try this example instead:

```
function getValues(objName)
{  
    var arr = new Array();
    arr = document.getElementsByName(objName);

    alert("total objects with name \"textfield\" = \n" + arr.length);

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        var obj = document.getElementsByName(objName).item(i);
        alert(obj.id + " =  " + obj.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but although your answer is close it is not quite right. First of all `.getElementsByName()` returns an `HTMLCollection`, which is array-like but not an actual array. Secondly you shouldn't initialise your `arr` variable to a new array because you then immediately overwrite that with the value returned by `.getElementsByName()` (it doesn't put the result into your array, it discards your array). Thirdly, why are you calling `.getElementsByName()` again on each iteration of your for loop?

Comment: If you just want to iterate over it then yes, the `.length` property and `[]` array notation will let you treat it like an array. But the code in your answer uses the `.item()` method, which is not an array method. And _real_ arrays have a bunch of other methods, like `.sort()`, `.join()`, etc.