# Access Form elements with "name" when no "ID" available

Tags: html, forms, getelementbyid, getelementsbyname

I'm new to scripting. I am trying to automate some web form filling tasks.

I was able to do most parts where there was as HTML "ID" tag assigned.

For instance,

If the form has this:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="30" size="30" value=" " name="desc" id ="id1"></input>
```

I used something like below code to assign a value to the Textbox.

oIE.Document.All.Item("id1").Value = "MESSIAH1"

However, there are some forms that I am handling that have (code below):

```
<input type="text" maxlength="30" size="30" value=" " name="desc"></input>
```

No "Id", just "name"

What do we do here?
Any pointers?
In general, my question is how would I fill / access forms (elements) when I don't have an associated HTML "ID" , but just a "name".

Appreciate all help

*If it matters, I'm running VBSCRIPT on IE8.

Comment: Is it inside a form? Let's say myForm then you can access them via myForm.desc

Comment: There's a method to get elements by name : `document.getElementsByName` and it returns a node list of elements that match with the given name. If your names are unique you can use it like `document.getElementsByName("...")[0]`

Comment: VbScript client side!!! It may be 2nd time I heard/see this! I'm touched.

Comment: @Adriano yes of course. Your solution with using `form_id.element_name` is more useful for almost all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByName` returns an `HTMLCollection`. You can access the value of the first item like this:

```
document.getElementsByName("desc").item(0).value
```

Or like this:

```
document.getElementsByName("desc")[0].value
```

More info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

Font: [Using document.getElementsByName() isn't working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845886/using-document-getelementsbyname-isnt-working)

Comment: @user3408723 I changed the name of the field to DESC, it was TO. Please try again.