# Make a button invisible or visible using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to use an OnFocus event of a textbox in ASP.Net.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TBAccountNum" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" Height="12px" Width="100px" Font-Size="Small" AutoCompleteType="None"  Wrap="False" OnFocus="Validator()" OnTextChanged="TBAccountNum_OnLeave" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

The only way to do that is to use Javascript, which I know nothing about.  I found this little piece of code on SO that looks like it should work:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">

<script type="text/javascript">

    function Validator()
    {
        document.getElementsByName("btnValidateWork").style.visibility = "visible"; 
        document.getElementsByName("btnSubmitWork").style.visibility = "hidden"
    }
```

However, when I run it I get the following error:

> 0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of
>   the property 'visibility': object is null or undefined

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong (besides trying to write code I know nothing about...  :oP )?

All relevant code has now been posted.  I'm using IE9 on an Intranet (mandated by the company, so that can't change) if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByName("btnValidateWork") returns an htmlcollection. You have to iterate it, and for each item (node) add the proper css.

Check out this: [Using document.getElementsByName() isn't working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845886/using-document-getelementsbyname-isnt-working)

EDIT:

to use getElementsByName, your element(s) must have a name property. Example:

```
<button name="btnValidateWork">my button?</button>
document.getElementsByName("btnValidateWork")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisbenseler/h3dwwud6/

I think that a better approach is to use getElementsByClassName and add some class to it, and then do something like document.getElementsByClassName("hidden")

Comment: Should I have used GetElementsByID?  Any chance you can post the code that will actually work for me?

Comment: @JohnnyBones I edit my answer, with some code. Don't have to use ids, but you can. You can also use a class.

Comment: Now it's throwing this error: 0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined

Comment: Post some code (jsfiddle, codepen, etc...) so we can see what is happening.

Comment: Literally, there's nothing to post that's not posted above.  I've got a <asp:Textbox> with OnFocus="Validate()"  When I click in the textbox, it runs the Validate() function I posted in my question.

Comment: Post the markup/source of the html that your asp tag generates. document.getElementsByName("btnValidateWork") is returning null (or undefined).

Comment: I just read that you can't set the style of a control in ASP if it's hidden in the code-behind (btnName.Visible="false";), since technically it doesn't exist in the front end.  There's nothing to render.  Does that sound accurate?  I've had 5 people basically give me identical code so I can't think fo any other reason why it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

As said before `document.getElementsByName` returns a collection (array) of HTML-Objects. So you need to address them like this:

```
 function Validate()
    {
        // To access the first
        document.getElementsByName("btnValidateWork")[0].style.visibility = "visible"; 
        document.getElementsByName("btnSubmitWork")[0].style.visibility = "hidden"
        // To access all of them
       var i = 0,
           validWork = document.getElementsByName("btnValidateWork");
       for (i = 0; i < validWork.length; i++) {
           validWork[i].style.visibility = "visible";
           // ...
       }
    }
```

See a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/danielgasser/r3f5se5n/).

Comment: See the error I posted to Chris' question.  Same thing.

Comment: From the JavaScript part, it should work! the error must be somewhere else

Comment: The second part doesn't error, but it also doesn't do anything.  I'm usine IE9, does that matter?

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle or similar

Comment: @JohnnyBones Sry man. it works. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/danielgasser/r3f5se5n/